# Can anyone help me with importing Google Profile using ASP.net MVC 1.0 in my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, import, profile

I have searched on net about Google profile import.
I have successfully implemented importing of User Contacts into my application
but I am not able to import Google Profile.

Please do the needful.
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you describe your problem more into detail? Are you using something like OpenID in your application or are you allowing users to login with Google credentials and then *simulating* requests to google's site as if someone would access it via browser and get data from there?

Comment: @Robert ......i am using Google API but i am not finding a way to use those details to get me their "profile" information like first name ,last name ,age..... i want to user to login with their Gmail account and should also get logged in to MY WEBSITE (ie. Single Sign on).

Answer (score 0):

the Google Buzz API should have what you're looking for:

```
http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#people-self
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: HAy!! thanks, the link was useful , but the only problem that i came across this impementation is that ,the user's need to have a user profile created first and also need to keep his profile public , before the values can be accessed by us..So is their any way, to just get the user's First name and last name and place , without the user needing to create a PROFILE.

Comment: No, I don't think that'll work. The API is specifically designed to access Profile data; if the user hasn't created a public profile, then there's nothing for the API to access. (And if they haven't created a public representation for their account, then we shouldn't give you programmatic ways to surface the name on an account since they haven't made that info public through us.)